# How do I apply folder permissions in WiX, keeping existing permissions, but without recursion?

Tags: wix, wix3.6, directory-permissions

The following will apply (modify) permissions recursively, and respect current permissions:

```
<util:PermissionEx User="[MYUSER]" Domain="[NT_DOMAIN]" GenericRead="yes" GenericWrite="yes" GenericExecute="yes" Delete="yes" DeleteChild="yes" />
```

But, I don't want to apply it recursively!

I want it non-recursively, i.e. just that folder and no children.

(I believe that the older  element clears the inheritance of permissions from the parent folder, which means it is no good for my purposes, as I must preserve existing permissions).

Is there any way to tell PermissionsEx not to apply the permissions recursively? Can I combine PermissionEx and Permission nodes in some way to get the desired effect? Or is my only option to issue a custom action command line call to cacls.exe?

Comment: Just gave up and used cacls in the end:

    <CustomAction Id="SetWebFolderPermissionNonRecursive" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION"
                  ExeCommand='cacls "[INSTALLLOCATION_NO_TRAILING_SLASH]" /e /g [NT_DOMAIN]\\[APP_OFFLINE_HTM_COPY_USER]:C'
                  Return="check" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure any of the three built-in patterns ( two from MSI and one from WiX extension ) handle this scenario.  FWIW, I think it's not really a function of the object that you are setting permissions on rather a function of all the child objects that have choosen to inherit.  In other words,  the parent doesn't enforce propogation the childen opt into inheritance.

So you might have to do some reflection of all the children and then set them to block propogation.  The effort and risk is high so I'd wonder why this is actually needed and if you couldn't just create your own new child directory and set the permissions there that way you didn't have to worry about this problem.

Comment: I think what you are saying here, is that in windows explorer, the default is for folders to inherit parent permissions, and that makes sense. However, I believe the old style WiX Permission node didn't act recursively, so it's odd this newer extension doesn't have the option to have recursion off or on. I'm thinking it's to do with it respecting current permissions, which probably means that it also respects current inheritance permissions too. The main problem with WiX seems to be the (lack of) decent documentation which wastes so much dev time testing things out.

Comment: Re: "I'd wonder why this is actually needed and if you couldn't just create your own new child directory and set the permissions there". Because it's the root web dir (I need to give permissions to a specific user the rights to copy the app_offline.htm file there), i.e. I don't have a choice as it's MS functionality that decides the file and folder location.

Comment: Ah, I've seen similar things with clientaccesspolicy.xml. It's a design oversight on the part of MSFT if you ask me.